# getting yum to honor rpm weak dependency

Tags: rpm, yum, rhel, rhel7, rpm-spec

I have three rpm packages a, b, c.

a.spec has:

> Requires: X
>
> Suggests: b

b.spec and c.spec both have:

> Provides: X

When I create a local yum repo with these three rpms and try to install a.rpm, using `yum install a`, it is always `a` and `c` that get installed. yum is ignoring the weak dependency rule given here - https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:WeakDependencies . I am trying this on RHEL7.4 . Am I doing something wrong here ? What should I do to have yum prefer `b` over `c` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can on that OS - [this source](https://weldr.io/RPM-Dependencies/) says that weak dependencies are new in RPM **4.13**, while [this listing](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/) says that CentOS7 ships with **4.11**.

Comment: Right. And yum codebase never even touched anything related to weak deps. If you want to use weak deps, then you can install DNF, which is available for RHEL7 in EPEL. However, even DNF will ignore Suggests as it is just hint. And if you want to prefer B, then you must put there "Recommends: b".